# Python, loop through files in a folder and do a word count

Tags: python

I am new to python and I need to write a script that counts all the words in all the txt files in a directory. This is what I have so far, the else works when just opening a txt file, but when I enter a directory it fails. I know I need an append somewhere, I have tried it a few different ways but with little luck.

*edit I would like the results to be lumped together. So far its 2 separate results. I tried making a new list and having it appended with counter. but it broke. Thanks again, this is a good community

```
import re
import os
import sys
import os.path
import fnmatch
import collections

def search( file ):

    if os.path.isdir(path) == True:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                words = re.findall('\w+', open(file).read().lower())
                ignore = ['the','a','if','in','it','of','or','on','and','to']
                counter=collections.Counter(x for x in words if x not in ignore)
                print(counter.most_common(10))

    else:
        words = re.findall('\w+', open(path).read().lower())
        ignore = ['the','a','if','in','it','of','or','on','and','to']
        counter=collections.Counter(x for x in words if x not in ignore)
        print(counter.most_common(10))

path = input("Enter file and path, place ' before and after the file path: ")
search(path)

raw_input("Press enter to close: ")
```

Comment: What does it mean "it fails"? Beside that, I can't see a `.txt` limitation anywhere.

Comment: `if os.path.isdir(path) == True` could be shortened to `if os.path.isdir(path)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change line 14 to:

```
words = re.findall('\w+', open(os.path.join(root, file)).read().lower())
```

Also, if you replace the input line with

```
path = raw_input("Enter file and path")
```

Then you won't need to include ' before and after the path

Comment: Thanks so much, i knew it was something minor. I over looked this. Should i add another list and just have counter=collections.Counter(x for x in words if x not in ignore) append to new list then print it?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do. Do you just want to print the number of times each word appears in each file? Do you want to find the most common words in _all_ the files?

Comment: atm it prints the 10 most common used words for each file. seperately. i want it to give me the 10 most common used words from all the files combined. ty

Comment: Then don't append to the list, just add the counter on. That is, create an empty counter at the start: `total_counter = collections.Counter()`, then have `total_counter += counter` for each file. (Counters are designed so they can be added together)

Answer (score 2):

When iterating the results of `os.walk`, `file` will contain just the filename without the directory containing it. You need to join the directory name with the filename:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
        #do processing on file_path here
```

I recommend moving the code that processes a file to its own function - this way you won't need to write it twice, and it will be easier to debug problems.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the parameter for the function definition is wrong.  It should be:

```
def search(path):
```

The *ignore* is correct but can be made faster by using a set instead of a list:

```
ignore = set(['the','a','if','in','it','of','or','on','and','to'])
```

Otherwise, this is nice looking code :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
for file in files:
    fullPath="%s/%s"%(path,file)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the "files" list only contains the file names, not the full paths.
You have to use :

import os.path

...

and replace "open(file)" by "open(os.path.join(root,file))".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at [generator tricks for system programmers by David M. Beazley](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/index.html). it shows how to create little generator loops to do everything you have here. Basically, using the [gengrep](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/gengrep.py) example, but replacing grep with word counting:

```
# gencount.py
#
# Count the words in  a sequence of lines

import re, collections
def gen_count(lines):
    patc = re.compile('\w+')
    ignore = ['the','a','if','in','it','of','or','on','and','to']
    for line in lines:
        words = patc.findall(line)
        counter=collections.Counter(x for x in words if x not in ignore)
        for count in counter.most_common(10):
            yield count

# Example use

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from genfind import  gen_find
    from genopen import  gen_open
    from gencat  import  gen_cat
    path = raw_input("Enter file and path, place ' before and after the file path: ")

    findnames = gen_find("*.txt",path)
    openfiles = gen_open(findnames)
    alllines = gen_cat(openfiles)

    currcount = gen_count(alllines)
    for c in currcount:
        print c
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should have two functions: one that goes through a file and counts the words, and another that goes through the files in a directory and recursively calls itself when it finds directories. The per-file function should take a full path to the file and open the file itself.
- Reading the whole file in at once might run you out of memory. A line-by-line approach is better. Even better than that would be to write a generator function that reads, say, 4K at a time and outputs individual words, but that might be going overboard for this assignment.
- Look at `os.path.walk()`.
- Use `raw_input` if you're using Python 2. People *will* ignore that "quote the path" prompt.